# syncfusion winrt chart

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, syncfusion

I'm trying to use a Pie Chart from the SyncFusion WinRT Studio in my new Win8 C#/XAML store app, and I can't figure out how to set the data on the chart.  I have the chart on my page and have tried everything I can find to set the data to make things show up, but I can't get it to work.  The sample apps aren't much help because there is 0 code in their pages and I can't figure out what's different.  The chart below is copied right from their sample, but it doesn't work in my app.  Anyone have any samples of using a SyncFusion chart in a WinRT app?

Chart in XAML:

```
      <Grid Margin="30,15,30,30" x:Name="ChartGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
          <local:Labelconvertor x:Key="labelconverter"/>
          <Style TargetType="Line" x:Key="lineStyle">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
          </Style>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemplate">
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource labelconverter}}" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0.5"></TextBlock>
          </DataTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="legend">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding Interior}"></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="10,5,5,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item.Expense}"></TextBlock>
              </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
          <local:PieChartViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20">
        </StackPanel>
        <chart:Chart x:Name="ScatterChart" AreaBorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Visible">
          <chart:Chart.Header>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="0,20,0,10">Agriculture Expenses Comparison</TextBlock>
          </chart:Chart.Header>
          <chart:Chart.PrimaryAxis>
            <chart:ChartAxis></chart:ChartAxis>
          </chart:Chart.PrimaryAxis>
          <chart:Chart.SecondaryAxis>
            <chart:ChartAxis></chart:ChartAxis>
          </chart:Chart.SecondaryAxis>
          <chart:Chart.Legend>
            <chart:ChartLegend  CornerRadius="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource legend}" CheckBoxVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="1">
            </chart:ChartLegend>
          </chart:Chart.Legend>
          <chart:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Expenditure}" XBindingPath="Expense" x:Name="pieSeries" ExplodeAll="{Binding Path=IsChecked,ElementName=chkExplode}" ExplodedRadius="{Binding Path=Value,ElementName=slRadius}" Palette="Metro" Label="Expenditures" YBindingPath="Amount">
            <chart:PieSeries.AdornmentsInfo>
              <chart:ChartAdornmentInfo AdornmentsPosition="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ConnectorLineStyle="{StaticResource lineStyle}" ShowConnectorLine="True" ConnectorHeight="30" ShowLabel="True"  LabelTemplate="{StaticResource labelTemplate}" SegmentLabelContent="YValue">
              </chart:ChartAdornmentInfo>
            </chart:PieSeries.AdornmentsInfo>
          </chart:PieSeries>
        </chart:Chart>
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Code-Behind called from the LoadState function: (I've tried all of these options and none of them work...)

```
  PieChartViewModel pvm = new PieChartViewModel();
  this.DefaultViewModel["PieChartViewModel"] = pvm;
  this.DefaultViewModel["DataContext"] = pvm;
  this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = pvm;
  this.DefaultViewModel["DefaultViewModel"] = pvm;
  this.ScatterChart.DataContext = pvm;
  this.ChartGrid.DataContext = pvm;
```

Object Definition:

```
public class PieChartViewModel
{
  public PieChartViewModel()
  {
    this.Expenditure = new List<CompanyExpense>();
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Seeds", Amount = 20d });
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Fertilizers", Amount = 23d });
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Insurance", Amount = 12d });
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Labor", Amount = 28d });
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Warehousing", Amount = 10d });
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Taxes", Amount = 10d });
    Expenditure.Add(new CompanyExpense() { Expense = "Truck", Amount = 10d });
  }
  public IList<CompanyExpense> Expenditure
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
public class CompanyExpense
{
  public string Expense { get; set; }
  public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to populate the pie chart using the same data without problem. Please find the sample at [PieChartDemo](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/101983/PieChart-490565448.zip)

Here is the document that explains how to configure Pie Chart: [PieChartHelp](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/General/UG_WinRT_Chart_%20Pie%20Chart%20Documentation-173804257.docx)

Following are the three APIs used for providing data for generating PieSeries,

1. `ItemsSource` - You can provide the data source using this property. Any IEnumerable can be given as data source.
2. `XBindingPath` - It is used to provide the path for category data in the source object.
3. `YBindingPath` - It is used to provide the path for numeric data in the source object.